# Prove that $\frac{ \partial F (x)}{ \partial x_1 } = f(x) $, where $F(x) = \int_{I_{a,x}} f(t) dt$

Tags: integration, proof-verification, partial-derivative, riemann-integration

In the book of *Mathematical Analysis II* by Zorich, at page 136, it is asked that

> Let $f : I_{a,b} → R$ be a continuous function defined on an interval
>   $I_{a,b} = \{x ∈ \mathbb{R}^n | a_i ≤ x_i ≤ b_i , i = 1, . . . , n\}$,
>   and let $F : I_{a,b} → \mathbb{R}^1 $ be defined by the equality
>
> $$F(x) = \int_{I_{a,x}} f(t) dt,$$
>
> where $I_{a,x} ⊂ I_{a,b}$. Find the partial derivatives of this
>   function with respect to the variables $x_1, . . . , x_n$.

### Proof:

Directly from the definition of partial derivative,

$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial x_1 } (x) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{ \int_{I_{a, x'} } f(t)dt  - \int_{I_{a,x}} f(t) dt}{ |h| },$$

where $x' = (x_1 + h, x_2, ..., x_n)$.

$$ = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{ \int_{I_{a, x'} } f(t)dt  - \int_{I_{a,x}} f(t) dt}{ |h| } $$

Lets define $G(x) = \int_{(a_2, a_3,..., a_n)}^{(x_2, x_3, ..., x_n)}$, then (since the double integral exist, we can deal with iterated integrals)
$$=  \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{ \int_{a_1}^{x_1 + h} G(t)dt - \int_{a_1}^{x_1} G(t)dt   }{ |h| } = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{ \int_{x_1}^{ x_1+  h} G(t)dt + \int_{a_1}^{x_1} G(t)dt - \int_{a_1}^{x_1} G(t)dt   }{ |h| } \\
= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{ \int_{x_1}^{x_1 + h} G(t)dt}{ |h| },$$

and by the Fundamental theorem of calculus, this equals to 
$$ = G(x)$$

**Note:** $G(x)$ denotes the $(n-1)$ dimensional integral of $f$ over the interval $I_{(a_2, a_3,..., a_n), (x_2, x_3, ..., x_n)}$.

**Question:**

Is there anything wrong with this proof ?

Comment: $G(x)$ is the integration of what?

Comment: @57Jimmy See my edit please.

Comment: So, the partial derivative with respect to each variable is the same??

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Actually, I do not know the actual answer, I was just hoping to find out by doing the proof :)

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown But if we think it in $\mathbb{R}^3$, resizing a cube in any direction, $x, y$ or $z$,  changes the volume in the same manner, so we can expect to find a symmetry in here, I guess.

Comment: @onurcanbektas Why don't you try this on an explicit function $f$ and see whether your argument holds up?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Well.., it didn't work :)

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Ok, I have found my mistake :)